# Magento - orders with NULL values in DB

Tags: mysql, magento

recently i've discovered that some orders in DB (`sales_flat_order`) have NULL values for all columns except: `entity_id`, `protect_code`, `store_name`, `created_at`, `updated_at` and `total_item_count`.

Those orders can be found via BO in Orders tab after applying `DESC` sorting.

First i thought that it may be connected when customer account is deleted, but it isn't.
Second guess was directed towards multifront architecture... but in this case i don't have idea how it could happen.

Did You encountered such problem in your projects ?

Thanks.

Comment: did u solve this problem? because I am facing the same issue for ratings,but at the frontend it is showing the values, but in the DB it is storing as null.

Comment: It seems that the problem was solved when solving a different problem, but I'm not able to tell which one :/ Have you asked question here ? Maybe i'll be able to help.

Comment: my issue was solved. It is happened because I have entered ratings for  only french store, But in the database I am checking for english store. So i have entered ratings for english store also. This is how my problem was solved.

Comment: hum, thanks for tip, i'll check how situation looks like with my stores

Answer (score 0):

Never have encountered such before, do you have any 3rd party modules, or 3rd party code installed, if so I would start debugging and disabling modules.  You may also look into your server configuration as well if you are doing any types of load balancing, caching, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your database / tables have InnoDB engine enabled